# Аналог команды touch в git.cmd под виндоуз

Tags: windows, git, touch

Есть ли какой-то аналог команды `touch` в git.cmd под виндоуз?
У меня вот такой ответ:
...>

```
touch test.txt
"touch" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

В help команда `touch` отсутствует, и никакой другой команды по созданию файла не нахожу там.

Comment: [`type nul > your_file.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756874/2881286)

Comment: Обычно в этой команде даже под Линуском смысла нет. Файл создаётся, перезаписывается, либо дополнется через `>` и `>>`.

Comment: Можно так: echo: > test.txt

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Egorithm, вы вот не правы. Вы когда-нибудь программой сборки `make` пользовались? Вот её работа очень сильно облегчается наличием команды `touch`.